# Keycloak login interceptor/filter

Tags: openid-connect, keycloak, keycloak-services

I have a requirement to customize/extend JWT token returned by Keycloak server after successfully login. Additional data will be stored in external service - so I need to somehow intercept/postfilter request -> call with REST for additional data -> modify JWT token -> return response. Can someone give me some information, what is the best aproach to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can add your own data to the token, but that token is signed (usually by private key, which is saved in the Keycloak). So any additional  data added to the token invalids signature = you will create invalid token. It is not a good idea to modify token outside of Keycloak. Check Keycloak mappers - they are usually used to add more details into the token.

Comment: Is that possible to implement rest call to external service in keycloak mapper?

Answer (score 1):

Go to client: Mappers: Add new mapper:

Name:   extraInfo

Mapper Type:    User Attribute

User Attribute: extraInfo

Token Claim Name:   extraInfo

Claim JSON Type:    String

Add to ID token:    ON

Add to access token:    ON

Add to userinfo:    ON

Multivalued:    ON

Aggregate attribute values: ON

Go to Groups: create/select group: Attributes:

key: extraInfo

value: {"name":"We use JSON format as attribute", "id":"just any identifier"}

Assign user to that group

Relogin, check JWT token https://jwt.io/, you should get "extraInfo"